# db2 full text search in HADR mode

Tags: db2, full-text-search, db2-luw

We are trying to use db2 full text search. We will be using DB2 in HADR mode .where both the db2 instances will be hosted in different datacentres.
Hence we will have db2 full text server instances running on both the db instances.

I had a few questions on the same.

1) When db replication (sync) happens, will the index replication too happen on its own?
2) Is there any backup and synchronization of indexes required to be done as a part of HADR?

Answer (score 0):

`logindexbuild` and `indexrec` are probably what you want to consider ([link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0011691.html)).

Sounds like you want to use the index on both `Primary` and `Standby`, and setting `logindexbuild=on` is the way to go. Another benefit of keeping index immediately available in `Standby` is to reduce *role-switch*/*failover* time, since those indexes are already available in the new `Primary` and don't need to be rebuild.